# Smart Pointer in C with reference loops

Tags: c, smart-pointers, reference-counting

Aside from doing this in C (way too late to turn back now) I've written a couple of structs and functions that support reference counting for C. Essentially I've implemented C++ style Smart Pointers. My big problem, though, is that I'm using these in a graph (the kind with vertices and edges) and in the graph, my smart pointers are used. So if I have a node connected to an edge connected to another node but I don't have any more pointers to them myself, they each retain a pointer to each other. Therefore, the pointer counting won't hit 0 and they'll never free themselves. Is there a way to solve this problem without abandoning pointer counting altogether?

Comment: This is the sort of thing that gives garbage collectors the heebie-jeebies...or, at least, is the sort of thing that they have to deal with rather carefully.  And your problem is related to, though obviously not the same as, garbage collection.

Comment: No, that's pretty much my problem. I'm trying to write a programming language that compiles into C with memory management.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have a similar issue... :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142499/how-to-efficiently-reference-count-cons-cells-detecting-cycles

Comment: @PauloTorrens Kind of? Not really. From all the research I did on pointers all I was able to find was that its basically impossible to do this with pointer counting and I would have to implement a sort of flagging algorithm for the memory I've allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into how boost::weak_ptr is implemented to break cycles for shared_ptr.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves my problem. Imagine you have nodes a, b, and c, and stack reference s. Imagine they point to each other as s->a->b->c, and then s->b as well, and c->b as well. If we remove s from a, is there any verifiable way (without a BFS) to determine that s still points to it through b? Further, if we remove s from b, how does b know it should now be deleted and that neither a nor c are pointed to by s?

Comment: @Redian it sounds like `weak_ptr` could solve your problem.  The `weak_ptr` keeps a reference to the `shared_ptr`, but you cannot access the contents until you call `weak_ptr.lock()`.  If the `shared_ptr` is still valid it will have its reference count incremented.  If it is not you get `null` returned.  The main `shared_ptr` is not affected by the `weak_ptrs` and can be cleaned up when there are no concrete references to it.