# How to efficiently reference count cons cells (detecting cycles)?

Tags: c, optimization, lisp, automatic-ref-counting, cons

I need to make some sort of `liblisp` (in C11), and it will need to handle the basic functions, pretty much like what `libobjc` does for the Objective-C language.

## Edit

I'm rewritting the question to something less generic.

I got an implementation like this:

```
typedef struct cons {
  void *car, *cdr;
} *cons_t;

cons_t cons_init(void *, void *);
void *cons_get_car(cons_t);
void *cons_get_cdr(cons_t);
void cons_set_car(cons_t, void *);
void cons_set_cdr(cons_t, void *);
void cons_free(cons_t);
bool cons_is_managed(cons_t);
```

So I can make a cons cell (it uses a memory pool with reference counted objects). I can also use `cons_is_managed` to check if the cons cell is inside the memory pool (so you can use externally defined cells, not created with `cons_init` (like static data).

How could I efficiently implement an automatic reference counting here, making if someone calls `cons_set_car` or `cons_set_cdr` it would increment the reference count if the `void *` argument is a managed cons cell?

The harem and the tortoise problem wouldn't be useful here, because each cell have two possible ways to go (and it could go nowhere if car nor cdr are conses), they can be lists, trees, or graphs.

I should probably register external (non-managed) conses used in on `cons_set_car`/`cons_set_cdr` in order to find cycles that involve them, but I'm still not sure how to do this *efficiently*.

Since this is a more controled context then general cycles in graphs (max of two vertices on a node), is there any chance I could do this in linear time and avoid a garbage collection (which will be my plan B)?

The main problem is that this is the core of any functional languages, so those functions will be called **a lot** of times (like `obj_msgSend`), they are **the** bottleneck.

Thanks.

---

On a different approach, to simplify the question: how could one implement a cons cell on a language based on reference counting, like Objective-C + ARC or Vala?

Comment: Do you actually need to write this, or do you just need to use one?  There are some Lisps that compile down to C code and, I think, expose their data structures in C.  You might be able to simply reuse some of them.

Comment: Yeah, I actually need to write this. The Lisp compilers I found that make C code use raw structs to make this work, they don't use a runtime library, so the behaviour/optimizations is hardcoded on the compiler.

Comment: Whatever you do, you just have to name the library `isp`.  What way, you can use it from the command line with `-lisp`.

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff, fair enough. `libisp` it is. =P

Comment: The scope of this question is probably a bit too big for StackOverflow (it seems that you're essentially asking how to implement the runtime for a Common Lisp that exposes a C interface). My earlier comment mentioned implementations that compile to C, and you replied that those aren't great for this purpose.  What about implementations that allow you to define functions callable from C? E.g., LispWorks lets you do this with [`define-foreign-callable`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw445/FLI/html/fli-72.htm): "Defines a Lisp function which can be called from a foreign language."

Comment: Actually the question is about what strategies could be used in order to implement this. :( I will check LispWorks, though. :)

Comment: Anytime the word "best" is in a post, it invites the question to be closed.  "Best" is highly debatable and often not needed.  (One does not have to see the best doctor - it takes too long, but a good competent one.)   Consider editing your question to focus on an answerable question, like "how does my implementation fail?" or "how can I improve my implementation speed performance?"

Comment: Ok, I will do that. :)

Comment: Many lisp interpreters avoid completely the reference count. Instead, they use a garbage collector in case of leak of free nodes, because the average performance is often better (but it depends on the particular application!). In its basic implementation a GC uses a flag for each node and a "tree walker" applied on each atom's property to mark the used nodes. At the end, the nodes not marked are added to the list of free nodes. When the GC intervenes there is of course a peack of CPU load.

Comment: Why would the reference count increase just when using set-car and set-cdr?  It's really that if the value being _stored_ by set-car or set-cdr is a cons cell _x_, then _x_'s reference count should increase.  But _x_'s reference count should also increase if it's the value of a lexical variable captured by a closure, or it's an element of an array, or …, right?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor no, because it means that the cons cell may be found by looking on the car/cdr of another cell, so it should be preserved. For example, `cons_set_cdr(a, b)`, and `b` is a cons, the count on `b` should increase, as it is being used by `a`. Though I'm starting to think there is no way to do that without a simple GC...

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying about set-car and set-cdr (I may have misread the original question), but my point was that if you do `set_var(var83,b)` or `set_array_element(a,i,b)` and `b` is cons, this should cause `b`'s reference count to increase, too, right?  There are lots of things that can reference a cell, not just other cells.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor not in this case, since everything on functional languages are built from conses. Since this will be a library used in C, of course the user could use in other ways and should take care where he places the variables.

Comment: Your question talks about implementing a `liblisp`, but it really sounds like you're just talking about a linked-list library with garbage-collected nodes now.  Functional programming isn't anywhere near as useful if you don't have lexical closures, but lexical closures should count as references, it would seem to me.  What are you going to have in this library other than garbage collected cons cells?

Comment: E.g., if you write a higher-order function that takes a list and returns a function that takes a function and maps the function over the list: `(lambda (lst) (lambda (fn) (map fn lst)))`, the inner `lambda` expression that is returned clearly has a reference to the cons cell that is the value of `lst`, but this doesn't require `lst` to be the `car` or `cdr` of any other cons cell.

Comment: Yeah, of course, but in that case actually the lambda would return a cons list whose first argument would be a function pointer (or probably a SEL pointer), so it would indeed have a reference to `lst`, cause it would be the cdr of the returned lambda.

Comment: @PauloTorrens I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  The list `'(lambda (fn) (map fn list))` is built from cons cells and symbols, but the function that is the result of evaluating it should be a lexical closure that that includes a reference to the lexical environment in which `lst` is defined.  You _could_ represent the lexical environment using conses, I suppose, and so guarantee that referenced objects are always referenced as the `car` or `cdr` of a cons cell, but that's by no means a universal convention (indeed, it's probably rather _uncommon_, because it will make lexical

Comment: @PauloTorrens references, which usually can be a constant time memory lookup, rather expensive.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the idea is to save lexical state in a cons list, or a vector (which should be faster), then use an assembly function (like `cons_call_lambda` or something) to run it. I think of implementing it this way because it will ease the work of `eval`, because the memory will already be on the same model both ways, with the function pointer as the `car` of the list, in the case of a lambda, or a `SEL`, in the case of a call by name (so it would be something similar to `objc_msgSend(global_lisp_environment, car_from_list_as_SEL_with_message_name, cdr_from_list_as_args)`).

Comment: If you want to impelment anything with reference counting, you should skip Objective C and head straight for C++, where you can create "smart pointer" classes. A reference-counted library of Lispy objects is a breeze to create in C++.  And, thanks to const reference parameters, you can eliminate a lot of the overhead of bumping refcounts, across your function calls. When a reference to an object is passed to `func` as `void func(const objref &)`, it's just a lexical binding of a reference to the existing smart pointer: no ref bump happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the main goal of the reference counting that you are aiming to implement is efficient garbage collection (even though you say "avoid garbage collection", it is clear that you are aiming to implement automatic memory management).

First, I would advise you to consider whether to instead switch to some sort of [tracing garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection), such as most modern Lisp implementations use.  The basic difference between that and a reference counting garbage collection is positive vs. negative relationship to memory: with reference-counting, allocated elements are assumed to be live until proved otherwise (typically by a graph traversal algorithm).  With tracing, allocated elements are assumed to be garbage until proved otherwise (by reachability from a root set of objects, such as the REPL interface).

Yes, you can get an occasional significant performance hit when mark-and-sweep algorithms are running, but depending on the use you are aiming for with your library that may be worth it.  Similarly, if you manage threading carefully, you can have one core handling garbage collection while the other continues execution.  Most efficiently, there are hybrid strategies, such as performing a "cheap" reference counting that cannot handle cycles to take care of the high-frequency easy cases, then using tracing methods to collect the cyclic garbage as it accumulates.

As for how to do it efficiently... if you want to do reference counting, you need to store one number per cons.  Why not just store it in the struct?

```
typedef struct cons {
   void *car, *cdr;
   size_t reference_count;
} *cons_t;
```

If you adopt a hybrid strategy, then high-frequency operations like list processing in maps, reductions, and recursive functions can be handled in O(n) time where n is the number of elements to be garbage collected.

Comment: I've found a good solution; the [Inferno OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_%28operating_system%29) has a really nice algorithm to collect garbage with reference counting which can make it incrementally - it don't need to stop the world to collect, which is perfect for what I needed. If you can edit your answer to mention that, I'll gladly accept it. :)

Comment: @PauloTorrens I'd prefer not to make my answer dependent on a relatively obscure OS; I would recommend you instead self-answer and accept that.